# Convergence of equation, derived in set where it is divergent (repeated integration)

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence

So I notice that sometimes when you ignore set of convergence, you can obtain some true equations, if after transformations you will come back to set when equation will be convergent. And I have question about that one I got today. The equation looks like;

$k^{x+y}=\lim\limits_{a \rightarrow 0^-} -sin(\pi a)\int_{-\infty}^x \frac{ \left(\frac{y }{x-t}\right)^a  k^t }{ \pi (x+y-t)}dt  $

I' am not shure whether this should work (and whetere I do not make some misteake while deriving it) because I'm not formally studied matematition. I was just exploring some ideas. I just noticed that for $a \rightarrow 0^-$ equation growth with respect to t is the same that gives convergence for Cauchy's formula for repeated integration.

**Derivation of equation**

From Cauchy's formula for repeated integration we know that;

$f^{(-n)}(x)=\frac{\int_a^x \left( x-t \right)^{n-1}f(t) dt}{(n-1)!}$, where n is the number of repeated integration and $n>0$

We can use that to write down that for
$f(x)=k^x$,

$f^{(-n)}(x)=k^x (ln(k))^{-n}=\frac{\int_{-\infty}^x \left( x-t \right)^{n-1}k^t dt}{(n-1)!}$

We can write it as

$f^{(n)}(x)=k^x (ln(k))^{n}=\frac{\int_{-\infty}^x \left( x-t \right)^{-n-1}k^t dt}{(-n-1)!}$, $n<0$

And than multiply both sides by $\frac{  y ^{n}}{(n)!}$

$\frac{k^x  (y ln(k))^{n}}{(n)!}=\frac{\int_{-\infty}^x y^n \left( x-t \right)^{-n-1}k^t dt}{(n!)(-n-1)!}$

We can use properties of factorials (Gamma function) and Euler's formula to write down;

$\frac{1}{(n!)(-n-1)!}=-\frac{sin(\pi n)}{\pi}=\frac{e^{-i \pi n}-e^{i \pi n}}{2 \pi i}$

At this point let's ignore set of convergence and let's write down that;

$k^{(x+y)}$

$=\lim\limits_{a \rightarrow 0^-} \sum_{n=a}^{\infty}\frac{k^t  (y ln(k))^{n}}{(n)!}$

$=\lim\limits_{a \rightarrow 0^-} \sum_{n=a}^{\infty}\frac{\int_{-\infty}^x \left( e^{-i \pi n}-e^{i \pi n} \right)y^n \left( x-t \right)^{-n-1}k^t dt}{2 \pi i} $

$=\lim\limits_{a \rightarrow 0^-} \int_{-\infty}^x \sum_{n=a}^{\infty}\frac{ \left(\left(\frac{ye^{-i \pi }}{x-t}\right)^n-\left(\frac{ye^{i \pi }}{x-t}\right)^n\right)  k^t }{2 \pi i(x-t)} dt$

$=\lim\limits_{a \rightarrow 0^-} \int_{-\infty}^x\frac{  \left(\left(\frac{ye^{-i \pi }}{x-t}\right)^a-\left(\frac{ye^{i \pi }}{x-t}\right)^a\right)  k^t }{2 \pi i(x-t)\left( 1+\frac{y}{x-t}\right)} dt$

$=\lim\limits_{a \rightarrow 0^-} -sin(\pi a)\int_{-\infty}^x \frac{ \left(\frac{y }{x-t}\right)^a  k^t }{ \pi (x+y-t)}dt $